# Know which one of two linux devices is the host when using USB OTG?

Tags: usb, usb-otg

I have a raspberry pi connected to a linux computer by a USB 2.0 type A OTG cable. The problem is I don't know which one is the host. How can I know that?

Comment: If the linux computer is a desktop, with near certainty it is the host, because desktop computers don't have the hardware to be USB clients or USB OTG (if you find one that can, please tell, I'd be very interested). If the linux computer is another embedded computer (e.g. another RaspPi), it gets more interesting...

Comment: the usb modules in use on the gadget side are different, they are usb gadget modules usually with a name like g_* . So if g_* kernel modules are in use it's *not* the host